# StringBuilder to Streams and Lambda expressions

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream, bufferedreader, stringbuilder

I have a method:

```
public String tpeResponse(InputStream is) {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
        String line;

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            out.append(line);
        }
        reader.close();
        is.close();
        return out.toString();
}
```

In line: `out.append(line);` I got an error:

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Please, help me to rebuild this method using Streams and lambda expressions.

Comment: The problem seems to be that the file you want to read is too big for your Java application to hold in memory. I'm not sure how streams or lambda expressions would help You still need to return a sting and whatever method you do to generate it is likely to still hit the memory limit. Either increase the limit or don't read the file into a string, if possible. Instead read and process it in chunks or with a moving pointer or whatever.

Comment: Since you got an `OutOfMemoryError`, I think you've got bigger problems than "writing this using streams and lambda expressions".

Comment: OutOfMemoryError occurs when the data is too huge. Increase your heap size and it will resolve your issue

Comment: That Will not help on the memory problem. What do you need to do?

Comment: you need to use Try-with-resources for `BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is))` that would reduce memory leak incase of failure

Answer (score 3):

Whatever you're reading data from (That `is` variable that is passed into your method) is either

- [A] endless (for example if it's `System.in`, which is an `InputStream` representing your process's standard in, and you started the app with `java -jar yourapp.jar </dev/null`, then it's literally endless.
- or, [B] not endless, but a *LOT* of data. For example, same situation but you do `java -jar yourapp.jar </my/20gigabyte4kCopyOfTheEntireLordOfTheRingsTrilogy.mp4`.

a `StringBuilder` just stores all data in your process memory which is limited. How limited? Well, certainly not more than the total amount of RAM in your computer, but usually a less than that, depends on how you started the JVM. If you're hitting that limit though, the answer is to not use StringBuilder whatsoever.

There are a few solutions. Which one is correct? Can't tell from the limited details you provided in the question:

- Realize that it's infinite input so it's simply impossible to try to store it all.
- Adopt a streaming model, where instead of turning all the input into a big string and then processing the string, instead grab enough input that you can operate on that, operate on it, and then keep going.

For example, imagine you have an app that counts the number of times the word 'hey' appears in an inputstream.

Instead of writing it the way you did, instead you could do:

```java
public int countHey(InputStream is) {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    String line;

    int total = 0;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        total += countHeyInLine(line);
    }
    reader.close();
    is.close(); // WARNING! SEE BELOW!
    return total;
}
```

This code works even if you feed it the collected works of shakespeare, because this code reads one line, processes that line, reduces the result of this processing to a single value, and then moves on: Java's garbage collector can simply collect all lines you've processed, and this code therefore will merrily dig its way through all the millions of lines you tossed at it, without ever running out of memory.

NB: Whatever opens a resource should either also close it, or needs to be very clearly marked that it transfers the responsibility of closing it to whomever calls it. You've done the reverse: This method is **NOT** the code that created that inputstream but you ARE closing it. This is a very bad idea and leads to resource leaks. You should not be closing `is` and making clear in the docs that your code doesn't. Alternatively, if you feel it's best that this method closes `is`, it should do so in a try/finally structure, so that callers can rest assured that invoking this method WILL end up closing that stream, one way or another.

Comment: *Is* that a file, or something else? Do you *really* need it as a `String`?